# Network setup using wifi and powerline adapters

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, home-networking

I have a router from my provider which is attached to the ADSL (phone) socket.  The internal address of that router is 192.168.2.1.

It hooks into a powerline adapter so that the rest of the house can access the internet, for example a server that I have.  The server has address 192.168.2.110.

Also attached to the router is another router with wifi.  That router has address 192.168.2.250.  The wifi router has DHCP turned off.

Both routers have subnet mask 255.255.255.0

I am writing this from a laptop, which is attached to the network over the wifi router, and it has address 192.168.2.30.

If I attempt to connect to the server (192.168.2.110), from this laptop when its connected over wifi, I get no connection.

When I attach my laptop to the network using a cable and a powerline adapter, then I can connect to the server.

I can connect to the internet from both wifi connections (i.e. this laptop) and from the server (powerline network).

What could be the reason that the I can't connect to the server, when attaching to the network over wifi?

Comment: This "powerline adapter" - does it have a base-unit and several end-units, or only several identical units?
Can you link to it's website?

Comment: They are all the same, from Zyxel.

Answer (score 1):

You need to make your WiFi router work as an AccessPoint. You should have this feature somewhere on your administrator page. I can't give you more details, as the settings may differ from one router to another. I think you should have the setup in the manual as well.

Now you have two different networks, with the same network addresses, one of the WiFi router, one of the main router and power-line adapter.

Comment: OK, I read the manual, and I also have to turn off upnp.  RTFM :-)

Comment: UPnP is not that of a deal, it might be useful one day. Anyway, the idea is that you don't want to use the second router as a router, but as an invisible extension to your existing network, and that was the AP does.

Comment: I'll reboot it and see if it works...

Comment: No joy.  Might be that this wifi router is so old that it doesn't support being an access point... (circa 2005)

Comment: Give me the name of your router.

Comment: Read the manual some more, and now its set up as an access point.  I can't connect to the server though, but that could be something else, like it needing a reboot.  No time at the moment, I will play later...